# How to get the unique identifier of the log stream for a AWS lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

**Context:**
We have a Lambda python function with many simultaneous invocations of the same function creating many unique log streams in cloudwatch. Additionally we use Xray on this lambda function. Using Xray we can quickly find an erroring invocation, however going from Xray to Cloudwatch is a pain, because the "Search Log Group" feature in the AWS console does not work as it will simply not load. Loading a specific log stream will work easily, hence we would like to annotate the Xray events with the name of the log stream.

**Question:**
The unique identifier of the log stream uniquely identifies the container on which the lambda is running. I do not know however to get this id from inside to function such that I can pass it to xray. How to get the unique identifier of the log stream from inside a lambda function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out all [the environment variables that are present](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-environment-variables.html) in the AWS Lambda runtime environment. Specifically `AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME` and `AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME`.